# Does anyone have experience with small heat-recovery air exchangers?

Tags: hvac, vent, energy-efficiency

I know there are units made which are supposed to be sized for use in a residential kitchen, as a more efficient replacement for the usual vent hood (bring air in to replace air blown out, but transfer heat between the two so you don't lose as much heating/cooling as you would with a normal just-blow-outward setup). I like the idea, but they ARE more expensive (of course; two fans and the heat exchanger and the internal ductwork to feed it) and I'm not sure how much maintenance they need... especially since in a kitchen setting you're going to get airborne grease and so on which may make keeping it working efficiently difficult.

So: If you've installed one of these, how did it work out and would you do it again?

Comment: Huh - due to the grease issue I've never seen or expected to see a kitchen one. I suppose with metal exchanger sections it could work.

Comment: I've installed HRV's on HVAC systems and they're kinda big... Link? [can-an-hrv-replace-the-air-exhausted-by-a-range-hood](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/11118/can-an-hrv-replace-the-air-exhausted-by-a-range-hood), [can-kitchen-downdraft-fan-be-connected-hrv](http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/blogs/dept/qa-spotlight/can-kitchen-downdraft-fan-be-connected-hrv) -Also, was what you were looking at *sized to fit in*, or intended to be *directly* hooked to the exhaust?

Comment: There are a few smaller ones, according to websearch for "residential kitchen heat recovery" -- though it's unclear how well they really would work in that environment. The ones I've seen are sized to fit in a wall opening rather than being hooked to an exhaust hood; they're aimed more at general air exchange than task collection. I suppose one could use a filtering hood which vents back into the room to catch most of the splatter, then let the HRV deal with exhausting fumes/moisture left over... but I'm not convinced either. Interested, though, if practical.

Comment: My experience of the hood fans that blow back into the room is that the effect of whatever filters they have is miniscule, and I hate them. YMMV.

Comment: Absolutely agreed. But ideally I'd like to avoid losing heated/cooled air when I use an exhaust, so I'm looking for a miracle of some flavor. If I could run a hood into a heat exchanger, that'd do the job, but...

Comment: I'm putting this up as a comment because it isn't really an answer.  Check out this site and this blog entry to get started with your HRV idea: http://www.qa-greenbuildingadvisor.com/blogs/dept/energy-solutions/providing-fresh-air-our-home

Comment: You might also look at the Panasonic Spot ERV for a low(er) cost single space (not whole house) solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the grease and other unwanted fumes being exhausted this is not a good idea for a range hood in the kitchen. You would be surprised at how easily grease builds.

Comment: That's what I was concerned about,  certainly.  A pity ...

Comment: Hm. I have an idea for a simple "scrubber" which might solve that,  if the hrv can handle high humidity ...